# как регулярно возобновлять воспроизведение музыки в sfml c++

Tags: c++, sfml

В меню приложения играет фоновая музыка, нужно, что бы по окончанию, песня воспроизводилась заново.

Comment: setLoop(true) от вашего объекта sf::Music